# Splitting Panes in XCode - I Wish I had My Emacs :(

Tags: xcode

I finally figured out how to split panes in Xcode, and I even finally found out that if I hold option when I split panes, I can do a vertical split too.

But I seem to have run into a bug. When I spawn a separate text editor and split panes within it, I can split panes horizontally, or vertically, but not both. Has anyone else run into this?

However, if I split within the main project window, which includes Groups & Files pane, I can split both ways.

What's the deal?

Oh how I wish I could just do Cocoa in emacs. C-x 0,2,3, and my favorite C-x C-f.

While I'm at it, how do I jump down a block, like I would do with ctrl-down in emacs?

Comment: grrr im in XCode 4 and I split an editor pane and emacs is all right I guess but apart from that I can't figure out how to close my second split pane grrr.

Answer (score 1):

That certainly seems to be a bug; you should [file it with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).

> Oh how I wish I could just do cocoa in emacs

What's stopping you? Cocoa code is just made up of text files like anything else. I've certainly never had any problems editing Objective-C in vi.

Comment: You can also use xcodebuild to free yourself more from XCode. I'm still addicted to the code-completion, though.